# Search data with modal in laravel

Tags: php, frameworks, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

I have 3 tables in the database.

1. Customer Table.
2. Item Table.
3. Goods Ordering Desk.

I want to do a search using # boostrap-modal, that is, when I want to add data to the order form there is already a button to display # boostrap-modal and in that #modal there are data items in the form of tables and data search text in the table, done. but the problem arises when I want to find data when I submit the modal search button, #modal is missing, I understand because it happens because when we submit we will load / refresh the page so that the modal is lost. What I want to ask is how to prevent that #modal from being lost when I look for data about this #modal?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this using AJAX. You can prevent the default submit action of the button using preventdefault in jquery.

`document.getElementById("idofsubmitbutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){ event.preventDefault() });`

Then use ajax to submit the form to the route. Then as soon as get response from the ajax call, take the necessary action.

https://codingdriver.com/laravel-7-form-submit-using-ajax-with-validations-example.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try.